# how to use classify.py classify not image data?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I can use the classify.py run the cat.jpg example.But my project use the txt data . just like use 1,2,3,4 I can get a number . I have got the  xxx.caffemodel now , can I use classify.py to get my predicted answer or I must write some new code .  Hope somebody help me .Thank you !!!

Comment: As you mentioned `.caffemodel`, you must be talking about neural network. You can specify input type by defining input layer in NN. To take 10 by 10 gray scale image as an input, you need 100 nodes in the input layer. For 20 by 20 RGB images, you need an input layer of the shape 400 * 3. It is not the problem of file format, but the problem of how to parse raw data and fit them into the input layer.

Comment: I have solved this problem . Still thank you for answer!